# What is a tuple module in Erlang?

Tags: module, erlang, tuples

http://www.erlang.org/news/35 mentioned that this will be documented, but I can't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A "tuple module" is a tuple with two elements, the name of a module and a list of extra arguments.  For example:

```
{my_module, [foo, bar]}
```

Such a tuple can be used instead of a module name in function calls.  In this case, the function being called will get the tuple in question as an additional argument at the end of the argument list:

```
3> Module = {lists, [[foo]]}.
{lists,[[foo]]}
4> Module:append([bar]).
[bar|{lists,[[foo]]}]
```

This call is equivalent to:

```
7> lists:append([bar], {lists, [[foo]]}).
[bar|{lists,[[foo]]}]
```

Tuple modules are kept for backwards compatibility, as they were the implementation mechanism for [parameterised modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339012/parameterised-modules-in-erlang), which were removed from the language in R16.

Comment: hum, I was expecting [foo, bar] as the end result

Comment: Me too, thus my choice of function for testing :)

Comment: Attention for example! Standard library not suit for this calling, because last argument alwasy the whole tuple with module qualification, which not expected by std modules as `lists` etc. Arguments not extracted for compiler consider arity. This can be useful with new modules like this: https://github.com/comtihon/mongodb-erlang.