# Define a constant module in elixir

Tags: testing, mocking, elixir

I would like to create some changeable boundary module. Ideally the result would look like any other module but the behaviour could be set at compile time or in the configuration files. I think I am looking for something like define in erlang

Say I have a SystemClock module and a DummyClock tuple module. Ideally the Clock module would be one or other of the two modules above chosen in the config file.

In `config/test.ex`

```
define(Clock, {DummyClock, 12345678})
```

Later

```
Clock.now
# => 12345678
```

In `config/prod.ex`

```
define(Clock, SystemClock)
```

Later

```
Clock.now
# => 32145687
```

Comment: For what it's worth define in Erlang is very much akin to  #define in C/C++.  That is it's basically string substitution.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do this is with configs and `Application.get_env/2`.

in `config/test.exs`

```
config :my_application, clock: DummyClock
```

in `config/dev.exs` and `config/prod.exs`

```
config :my_application, clock: RealClock
```

in the code that uses the clock

```
defp clock, do: Application.get_env(:my_application, :clock)

def my_function(arg1, arg2) do
  now = clock.now
  # ...
end
```

Comment: its a good answer, but I have been avoiding doing this as I want to not have to change existing code and be able to use it as a mocking mechanism. Ie within the application there should be no requirement on the developer to know to reach to the application setup.

Comment: There is a long thread on the mailing list where José explains why you don't need it. It starts here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/elixir-lang-talk/mocking/elixir-lang-talk/oYXyvEUi64Y/qRE9FzXBCQAJ

Comment: I have an opinion that in a few places they might be very useful. I have provided an example of a solution I have tried this afternoon here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elixir-lang-talk/uIrA6Y0rvpU

Answer (score 0):

An option that I've used many times is `Meck`, which [you can get/read about here](https://github.com/eproxus/meck).  For your example, we might write something like:

```
test "something that depends on Clock calls Clock.now" do
  :meck.new(Clock, [])
  :meck.expect(Clock, :now, fn -> 12345678 end)

  # we expect that the module under test is getting it's result from Clock
  assert ModuleUnderTest.execute  == 12345678
end
```

Instead of re-compiling your code to get `:test` behavior, `Meck` replaces the functionality of your modules on the fly, during your tests.

The discussion referenced in other comments here points out some reasons not to use mocking; Yes, you have to sacrifice certain things (sequential testing, and José's opinion of your testing code), but in exchange, you can dramatically simplify testing code in tricky situations.